# Defining a JS Variable to be Used Instead of Pasting The Text Over and Over

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is define a variable once, and then use that same text whenever it can be used.  Sometimes I use `alert`, `confirm` `return` etc so I created a quick example using all 3 in case the process is a little different depending on the usage

Example:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
var result = confirm("text that i want to create a var for here");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
alert("text that i want to create a var for here");
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return "text that i want to create a var for here";
});
```

What I tried to do was this:

```
var test = "text that i want to create a var for here";
```

and then I replaced the code above that with `test` wherever there is `"text that i want to create a var for here"` which didnt work so what is the correct way for me to define something once, and then use the variable in place of the text?

**Update:**

I have it working with a basic variable such as

```
var test = "testing text here"
```

but below is an example of what im having an issue with:

```
var test = "text row 1 \n\n text row 2 \n\n number "+number+" text row3"
```

I'm guessing its the "+number+" causing the issues for me so how do I fix that?

Comment: Are you really asking how to make a variable? Post the code you wrote with the variable that didn't work.

Comment: @Takendarkk the issue i was having was from using the `"+number+"` in the varialbe i was defining so thats why ti didnt work before, it works without it but how do I get the variable i created to work with `"+number+"`?

Comment: Post the WHOLE code so we can see all the parts and where they are.

Comment: @Takendarkk the rest is an external script, i just need to know how to create a variable with a variable in it

Comment: You did it correctly. That's why if it isn't working it really matters where the variable comes from. Help me help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this question is trolling. You need to define the variable before all callback functions needing the variable:

```
var myText = "text that i want to create a var for here"

$(document).mousemove(function(event){
var result = confirm(myText);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
alert(myText);
});
```

the last example is not appropriate: you cannot get the returning value of a callback function attached to a DOM event.

Comment: @l-cetinsoy hello! I updated the main question because it seems the reason it didnt work for me is because i have `"+number+"` in my javascript, how do I get the variable to work with that in it?

Comment: If you define the variable number before the variable test it should works. Try to look and understand eventual errors.